# using https in intranet get sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed

Tags: java, ssl, https, httpclient

I have some problems in HttpClient (3.x) and https.

Because in intranet, I only have IP address. Although the target has a public domain and a valid certificate, I can't access it in the intranet.

At first, I tried using IP address directly. Some servers can pass, but some can't. Why? I thought it would be all failed. These jdk are all different versions from 1.6.0_6 to 1.6.0_45, but the httpClient version are all the same (Jboss 4.2.3 Built-in). How to explain it?

I tried to add the public domain and IP mapping in /etc/hosts. But I still got this ValidatorException error. Finally I export the certificate then import into my jre cacerts, and it worked.

If I don't wanna to import the certificate file, how to fix it? I can ignore all https cerificate in my code, but is there any better idea?

Comment: Are you sure that failed servers are using a valid certificate? You mentioned you're on the interanet, some companies don't use globally valid certificates for internal servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! I found there is no matched root CA in the jvm. After importing, everything worked.